# Apply style when linked by id

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, focus

I think that's a dumb question, but I don't know how to do it.

Is it possible to apply styles (Javascript I guess) when I go to an specific element by a link with an id? If yes, how? Something like that: `<a href="#focusThis">Click</a>`

I will try to go more deeply into them. I mean something like `focus` in CSS but it should activate when a link (`a` element) is clicked, not by click the own focusable element.

I guess I didn't make it sufficiently clear, hope you get me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try use *target selector* (css3)

for example:

```
#focusThis:target {
   border:solid 1px red;
}
```

Comment: Reference: [`:target` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#target-pseudo).

Comment: Works prefectly! Thanks ;)

Comment: You welcome. So you can mark the answer as helpful. just click on the "V" sign... Thnkas